# tmux reEnter to a session and save a session

Tags: ubuntu, tmux, session, r

Using ubuntu (terminal) I could open tmux session and open my R program  then run the script, the script prints text on the scree. my question(s) are:
how to re enter the session and re follow what is happening in the programe? can I keep what is printed on the sreen during the seesion, how to save it and quit peacefully so nothing stops. is it okay if my internet connection disconnect.

Answer (score 7):

With the command `tmux ls` you will list every session of tmux available and you can find their ID to the far left side, you can also see whether you're attached or not and various other information.

To re-attach to the session use the command `tmux attach -t ID` and the ID you found out earlier. To scroll, press `Ctrl-b` then `[`, then you can move around as normally. (eg <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> or movement keys). Press `q` to quit scroll mode.

To detach from the session the simplest way would be to use a shortcut command. If you haven't changed the prefix key you can detach by first pushing down `ctrl+b` and then the key `d` which stands for detach.

Tmux doesn't need an internet connection to function.

Comment: The OP might be accessing his/her Ubuntu machine over the internet using something like ssh. @Ragia: if your connection drops, just reattach the session like Roxto said, and you'll be fine. Your programs will still be there, and any text that was preset will still be present.